# ReactQuill and MathQuill4Quill using Functional Components

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component, react-quill

I am using ReactQuill and need to easily integrate math equations into the text I'm writing with ReactQuill. I set up mathquill4quill, but the documentation is for React Class Components and I'm writing with React Functional Components.

The documentation says to do the following:

```
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  modules: {
    formula: true,
    toolbar: [['formula']]
  },
  theme: 'snow'
});

var enableMathQuillFormulaAuthoring = mathquill4quill();
  enableMathQuillFormulaAuthoring(reactQuill, {
    operators: [
      ["\\sqrt[n]{x}", "\\nthroot"],
      ["\\frac{x}{y}", "\\frac"],
    ],
  });
```

However, with functional components, ReactQuill is called as a component as follows:

```
        <ReactQuill
          theme="snow"
          id="editor"
          value={text}
          onChange={handleTextChange}
          modules={{
            toolbar: [
              ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike", "formula", "image"],
            ],
            formula: true,
            imageResize: {
              parchment: Quill.import("parchment"),
              modules: ["Resize", "DisplaySize", "Toolbar"],
            },
          }}
        />
```

I tried replace the declaration of quill with the following code:

```
  const reactQuill = useRef<ReactQuill | null>(null);
  enableMathQuillFormulaAuthoring(reactQuill.current?.getEditor(), {
    operators: [
      ["\\sqrt[n]{x}", "\\nthroot"],
      ["\\frac{x}{y}", "\\frac"],
    ],
  });
```

and then adding the ref to the ReactQuill component as follows:

```
<ReactQuill
          theme="snow"
          id="editor"
          value={text}
          onChange={handleTextChange}
          modules={{
            toolbar: [
              ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike", "formula", "image"],
            ],
            formula: true,
            imageResize: {
              parchment: Quill.import("parchment"),
              modules: ["Resize", "DisplaySize", "Toolbar"],
            },
          }}
        />
```

but the `enableMathQuillFormulaAuthoring` method isn't working. I'm assuming it has to do with how I am using the useRef hook, but I'm not sure and I can't find much documentation out there to help.

How can I get the `enableMathQuillFormulaAuthoring` to work with my functional ReactQuill component?